# Как сделать чтобы в grid отсчет шел со второго ряда?

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Как сделать так что б последующие элементы не лезли в пространство `grid-column: 1 / 3`. Можно ли это реализовать без добавления сторонних тегов в верстку, и без прописывание каждой кнопке её позиции? Я хочу получить табло простого калькулятора, с кнопкой включения в правом верхнем углу.

```css
.fild_buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.btn_number {
  display: block;
  height: 72.5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.btn_reset {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="fild_buttons">
  <button class="btn_number  btn_reset" type="button">RESET</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_7" type="button">7</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_8" type="button">8</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_9" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_divide " type="button">/</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_4" type="button">4</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_5" type="button">5</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_6" type="button">6</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_multiply" type="button">X</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_1" type="button">1</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_2" type="button">2</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_3" type="button">3</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_substract" type="button">-</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_0" type="button">0</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_point" type="button">.</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_result" type="button">=</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_plus" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь псевдоэлементом для создания пустоты:

```css
.fild_buttons:before {
  content: "";
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Результат:

```css
.fild_buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.btn_number {
  display: block;
  height: 72.5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.btn_reset {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.fild_buttons:before {
  content: "";
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="fild_buttons">
  <button class="btn_number  btn_reset" type="button">RESET</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_7" type="button">7</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_8" type="button">8</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_9" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_divide " type="button">/</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_4" type="button">4</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_5" type="button">5</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_6" type="button">6</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_multiply" type="button">X</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_1" type="button">1</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_2" type="button">2</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_3" type="button">3</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_substract" type="button">-</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_0" type="button">0</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_point" type="button">.</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_result" type="button">=</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_plus" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нашел, решение проще. Правда, пока не разобрался, почему оно работает. Просто не указывать для `.btn_reset {  grid-row: 1 / 2; }`

```css
.fild_buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.btn_number {
  display: block;
  height: 72.5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.btn_reset {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="fild_buttons">
  <button class="btn_number  btn_reset" type="button">RESET</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_7" type="button">7</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_8" type="button">8</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_9" type="button">9</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_divide " type="button">/</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_4" type="button">4</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_5" type="button">5</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_6" type="button">6</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_multiply" type="button">X</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_1" type="button">1</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_2" type="button">2</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_3" type="button">3</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_substract" type="button">-</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_0" type="button">0</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_point" type="button">.</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_result" type="button">=</button>
  <button class="btn_number  btn_plus" type="button">+</button>
</div>
```

Ну, и то что вышло → https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/JwjPWV

Comment: Классное решение! Оно работает, потому что сперва позиционируются элементы с явным позиционированием, затем автоматические. Так как у элемента не указана строка, то строка следующих элементов вычисляется автоматически, начиная с этого первого элемента и перед ним даже не ищется свободное место в строке. Можете подробней об этом почитать здесь https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-placement-algo там где упоминается "sparse". Также для более глубокого понимания полезно будет изучить свойство [`grid-auto-flow`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-auto-flow-property).

Comment: Собственно, значение `grid-auto-flow: row` по умолчанию и является корнем данного поведения.